# Seaweed snacks without lots of packaging

Tags: food, packaging

My kids like seaweed snacks but there’s so much packaging.  Alternatively I can buy crackers or raisins in large packages, reducing both the cost and packaging (plus if the package is cardboard it’s compost/recycle friendly). The downside is that those snacks aren’t as healthy.

How can we enjoy this kind of snack without all the plastic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make them yourself fairly easily by buying full sheets of seaweed in bulk at an Asian grocery store (some regular chain grocery stores carry them too). The big packs of seaweed do still contain plastic, but it’s less than in a single-serving container. “Roasted seaweed snack recipe” will get you lots of google hits. Here is one link: https://www.myrecipes.com/recipe/sesame-seaweed-snacks

They do need to be stored in a VERY airtight container. The single-use seaweed snacks I’ve purchased always had something similar to a silica gel packet and an absorbent napkin at the bottom as well, so if you won’t eat this right away those would be good to add to the storage container.